# Tooltip not working as expected

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I would like my tooltip to write the date and the value on hover. It should also update date and  value as you travel the value line on the chart.

I'm able to write one value but the date returns undefined and the value does not update as expected.

I'm new to D3 so I'm confused. Any help would be appreciated.

I posted a jsfiddle here:  [1]: http://jsfiddle.net/tommy6s/6L832q7e/
Thank you!

```
//draw tooltip div
var tooltip = d3.select(".wrapper").append("div")
   .attr("class", "tooltip");

                tooltip.append("p")
                .attr("class", "date")
                .html("<strong>" + d.date + "</strong>");

                tooltip.append("p")
                .attr("class", "value")
                .html("<span>" + d.value + "</span>");

           //tooltip code
            var path = svg.selectAll("path");

                path.on('mouseover', function(d){
                    tooltip.select('p', '.date').html(d[0].date)
                    tooltip.select('p', '.value').html('$ ' + d[1].value)
                    tooltip.style('display', 'block');
                });

                path.on('mouseout', function(){
                    tooltip.style('display', 'none');
                });

                path.on('mousemove', function(d){
                tooltip.style('left', (d3.event.pageX + 20) + 'px')
                  .style('top', (d3.event.pageY + 0) + 'px')          
                });
```

Comment: It looks like it should be `d.date` instead of `d[0].date`.

Comment: I tried d.date but it returns undefined.

Answer (score 0):

The problem you're running into is that you're creating an area chart. With an area chart, there's only one path. (The path is the entire region of the chart.) So the `mouseover` and `mouseout` events simply represent mouse movements on or off the area, and the associated data value for that area (it's the `d` parameter passed to the event handler) is the entire array of data points. You set that in your code with

```
focus.append("path")
    .datum(data)
```

To get your tooltip to work, you'll have to get the x and y properties of the mouse relative to the chart container (use the `d3.mouse()` function) and then translate those from the SVG coordinate ranges to the x- and y-domains of your data. With that information you can update the tooltip text appropriately. Note that you'll also have to update the tooltip text within the `mousemove` event to keep up with the mouse movement within the area.

Comment: Thanks Stephen! I'm going to try your suggestions.

Comment: I'm unable to figure this out. If I could get a hint on how to apply d3.mouse() function it would help me because I looked at the d3.mouse() api but did not understand how to apply it.

Comment: I'm trying to integrate the suggested demo into my chart. I made some improvement but the logic is messed up. If you could take a look at my fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/tommy6s/6L832q7e/ and provide some more input I'd appreciate it.